# display jquery var between elements without unique ids

Tags: jquery, class, variables, unique, show

I don't have much experience with jquery, but I've been trying to use it more and have run into a problem.

I'm trying to display a variable between certain elements that don't have unique classes or id's.

I just realized that the form elements I'm trying to show the variables before do have unique names, but I'm still not really sure how to show a variable before an element based on a name.

```
<td class="pme-key-1">Last Edit By</td>
<td class="pme-value-1">
<input class="pme-input-1" type="text" name="PME_data_LastEdit" value="10" size="60" maxlength="128" />
</td>
```

I'd like to use jquery to place the variable before the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When, so for example on which event do you want to display the variable and which element triggers this event? This would be the bit to just put the contents of yourvar in front of the input tag:

```
$("input.pme-input-1").before(yourvar);
```

If the name is unique, you can also use

```
$("input[name=PME_data_LastEdit]").before(yourvar);
```

Comment: Thanks that's all I needed. Like I said before, I'm a bit of a rookie when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: Everyone started as a rookie and this site is here for all us rookies to learn and improve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unique name for the selector, and before function to insert variable like this:

```
$('input[name="PME_data_LastEdit"]').before(variable)
```

Comment: This is what I did end up doing. Thanks for the response anyway! jm_toball just pointed me in the right direction first with the .before

Answer (score -1):

http://api.jquery.com/before/

```
var s = 'some string value';
$('#PME_data_LastEdit').before(s);
```

Comment: This ID does not exist, there's just a class and name. This would work fine if there would be an additional id though.

Comment: The selector is not correct, that selects by id, there is only a unique name field

Comment: That's true.  You could still do `$('input.pme-input-1')` or `$('input[name=PME_data_LastEdit]')` though.

Comment: My point wasn't the selector more so than it was the before() jQuery method.  But thanks for the -1 even though I gave a link to the jQuery api documentation first, that would explain in great detail.